I want to make a JavaScript hue inverter (add or subtract 180°), but it isn't working. How can I fix this?
In case you don't know, a hue inverter takes a value between 0 and 360, adds 180 if the input is less than or equal to 180, and subtracts 180 if the input is greater than 180. I added some JavaScript to do that operation, but it isn't working.
Here is the UI (there is no CSS yet): Click to see the image.


function invertHue() {
  const inputHue = Number(document.getElementById("hue-i").value);
  const outputHue = document.getElementById("hue-o").textContent;
  var result;

  try {
    if (inputHue <= 180 && inputHue > 0) {
      result = inputHue + 180;
      outputHue = result;
    } else if (inputHue > 180 && inputHue <= 360) {
      result = inputHue - 180;
      outputHue = result;
    } else {
      window.alert("The hue must be between 0 and 360.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    window.alert("There was an issue.");
  }
}
<div class="input">
  <input type="text" id="hue-i" placeholder="Enter hue here...">
  <button id="invert-btn" onclick="invertHue()">Invert</button>
</div>
<div class="output">
  <p id="hue-o">Inverted hue will appear here...</p>
</div>



What is going wrong in the code?
(p.s. I am using VS Code for my editor.)

Have you tried logging error instead of just alerting that there is an issue?

Also note that the calculation is much simpler: it's just (value + 180) % 360.

What does “isn’t working” mean in terms of behavior ([mre])? Also, don’t use try/catch to replace the detailed error information that you get in the console by default with an uninformative “There was an issue”.

What are you expecting to happen? You don't do anything with the result or outputHue.

The real issue of course being that you need to change the textContent of the element. const outputHue = document.getElementById("hue-o").textContent creates a new variable called outputHue that is completely unrelated to the element you're getting the textContent of. But then you have a ton of problems: const variables can't be reassigned; Don't use the onclick HTML attribute, add your listener on the JS side; window.alert can only show strings, you want console.log instead; don't try/catch, actually let your errors happen so you can spot and fix them; etc.

There are some fundamental problems here relating to programming works that are best fixed by (re)starting at the start with a good tutorial, and following that first, so you gain an understanding of how variables behave, how to write programs, etc.

You set outputHue to const, yet you're attempting to change it

Well, it turns out that I am an idiot... I don't know how I didn't notice that I used const instead of var. Also, I accepted the answer below because it works, but I guess my browser is acting weird or JavaScript isn't working (maybe it's disabled for some reason), because it didn't work when I implemented the code. Maybe I did something wrong there, too. I'll try to get this sorted out.

Also, I know exactly how variables behave and how to write programs, so there is no need to say that I do not. I just made a small error that anyone can easily make, especially when they change their mind about how they will use a variable or constant and forget to switch to or from var or const.

don't use const for input values, use it for the element itself


const
  inputHueElm  = document.querySelector('#hue-i')
, outputHueElm = document.querySelector('#hue-o')
  ;
function invertHue()
  {
  outputHueElm.textContent = ''
    ;
  let val = Number(inputHueElm.value)
    ;
  if ( isNaN(inputHueElm.value) )
    {
    window.alert('There was an issue... (not a number)')
    }
  else if (!Number.isInteger(val) || val < 0 || val > 360)
    {
    window.alert('The hue must be an integer between 0 and 360.')
    }
  else
    {
    outputHueElm.textContent = (val + 180) % 360;
    }
  }
<div class="input">
  <input type="text" id="hue-i" placeholder="Enter hue here...">
  <button id="invert-btn" onclick="invertHue()">Invert</button>
</div>
<div class="output">
  <p id="hue-o">Inverted hue will appear here...</p>
</div>



